# Rubymine debugger is failing on Macbook with M1 chip

Tags: debugging, apple-m1, arm64, rubymine

I recently switched to a Macbook with the M1 chip, but now when trying to run my project in debugger mode on Rubymine 2021.3.3 I get the following error:

```
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in 

`require': dlopen(/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debase-2.3.2/lib/debase_internals.bundle, 0x0009): tried: 
'/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debase-2.3.2/lib/debase_internals.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), 
    '/usr/local/lib/debase_internals.bundle' (no such file), 
    '/usr/lib/debase_internals.bundle' (no such file) 
    - /Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debase-2.3.2/lib/debase_internals.bundle (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I resolved this issue:

1. Uninstall Rubymine
2. Install the Appple Silicon version of Rubymine (I used the JetBrains Tool for this)
3. In the terminal run this command: 'gem uninstall debase' and selected to uninstall all versions.
4. Open Rubymine and your project
5. Click the debug button and select "yes" when the popup asks if you want to install missing debug gems
6. Next run 'bundle install' from the terminal (I ran this in Rubymine terminal). It installed debase 0.2.5.beta2

I am now up and running. Best of luck!

Fissh

Comment: Hey! Are you using rbenv or rvm to manage your ruby versions?

Comment: I was using "rbenv" at the time of my original post, but have since switched to "asdf" for version management.